# How can i pull out the column name in a dataframe when two conditions are met?

Tags: r, subset, extract

Here is my dataframe.

```
Name Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_4
A    4        1        0         1
B    5        0        0         1
C    2        0        1         0
D    1        0        1         1
```

I want to extract the name of the column when there is a 1 EXCLUSIVELY in a row where `column_1 <=2`.

In this example the only column that would work is `column_3`.

Comment: I don't understand your condition : why not also Column_4 (for row 2 )

Comment: Because there is also a 1 when `Column_1` is greater than 2. So I only want to pull out things that have a 1 ONLY when `Column_1` is equal to or greater than 2.

Comment: I think there’s a typo either in your question or in your wording - you probably meant `<=`, not `>=`

Comment: So why not also Column_2 that contains ONLY one `1`?

Comment: You're right I did have a typo! Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had 2 theories about what was asked theory 1: If we can assume that only 1's and 0's will be in the numbered columns then perhaps:

```
 colSums( dat[ dat$Column_1 >=2,     reduce the dataframe to only qualifying rows
            -1 ]) == 1   # remove letter column and make test.

#-------
Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_4 
   FALSE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE
```

You can use that to select from `names(dat)[-1]`

```
dput(dat)
structure(list(Name = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), Column_1 = c(4L, 5L, 2L, 1L), Column_2 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Column_3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Column_4 = c(1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Name", "Column_1", "Column_2", "Column_3", 
"Column_4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Theory 2:  (also get different answer than what you say is correct

```
sdat <- dat[ dat$Column_1 >=2,
         -1 ]
 sdat[ rowSums(sdat[-1]) == 1, ]
#-------
  Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_4
2        5        0        0        1
3        2        0        1        0

> names(sdat)[colSums( sdat[ rowSums(sdat[-1]) == 1, ]) == 1]
[1] "Column_3" "Column_4"
```

First the question said Column_1 needed to be >= and now it reads <= 2. So use the code for the second theory after simply reversing the inequality for row selection. When I do that now I do get just "Column_3.

```
sdat <- dat[ dat$Column_1 <= 2,
         -1 ]
 sdat[ rowSums(sdat[-1]) == 1, ]

 names(sdat)[colSums( sdat[ rowSums(sdat[-1]) == 1, ]) == 1]
#[1] "Column_3"
```

Comment: What i want is to pull out the column name when there is a 1 in that column ONLY when `Column_1` is smaller than 2.  So if a column has a 1 when `Column_1` is greater than 2 then it is automatically disqualified.

Comment: First you said Column_1 needed to be >= and now  <= 2. So you should be able to use the code for the second theory after simply reversing in inequality for row selection. When I do that now I do get just "Column_3.

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe* you want something like this:

```
a <- ...  
w <- apply(a[,-1], 2, FUN= function(x) {all(x[a$Column_1 > 2] == 0) & any(x == 1)})
```

The result is:

```
Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_4 
   FALSE    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE
```

We apply that function to all the columns of `a` (except the first column), and check that the column is always `0` when `Column1 > 2`, but there is at least one `1`.

The column name(s) then is

```
n <- names(a)[which(w)+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread('Name Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_4
A    4        1        0         1
B    5        0        0         1
C    2        0        1         0
D    1        0        1         1')

melt(dt[Column_1<=2 & Column_2+Column_3+Column_4==1], id = "Name")[value==1, .(variable)]

   variable
1: Column_3
```